# How to install AMD Radeon HD7450M Graphics Driver correctly on windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-8.1, drivers, graphics-card, amd-radeon

I have recently installed windows 8.1. And i have installed all drivers successfully except *AMD Radeon HD7450M Graphics Driver*.

I have downloaded the latest driver using catalyst auto-detect. At the end of the installation of this driver, the screen becomes black and after a few seconds it becomes blue with an error message `video_tdr_failure(atikmpag.sys)`.

I have tried several times, but the error persists. And at the third time of trying to install a different version of the driver, windows 8.1 crashed and I couldn't restart it again. I have reinstalled windows 8.1 again and now i am afraid of getting the same error again.

How can i resolve this problem?

**Note:**

- Dell Inspiron 14 N4050.
- Intel HD Graphics 3000.
- AMD Radeon HD7450M Graphics.

Comment: Did you try the Dell driver?[See this page](http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/04/product-support/product/inspiron-14-intel-n4050/drivers)

Comment: Yes i did and i got the same error @Moab

Comment: According to this [article](http://www.dell.com/support/article/sg/en/sgbsd1/SLN128811/EN) (see Inspiron Laptop section), the table informs that there is no update for dell n4050 drivers on windows 8.1. So what is the solution? waiting for updates? @Moab

Comment: try latest Beta: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/latest-catalyst-windows-beta.aspx remove the old installed driver before with DDU: http://www.wagnardmobile.com/DDU/ddudownload.htm